# How to install SQL database with wpf application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database

I'm working with WPF application with local SQL database using Visual Studio.

I'm wondering about how can I install the database together with the application to make it work properly on another computer?

Comment: What kind of SQL Database? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: I'm using sql server database

Comment: Ok, don't use the [tag:sql] tag for SQL Server. Use the [tag:sql-server] tag. [tag:sql] is for the standard "SQL" language, not for the product from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to get your app working with SQLite, which is a database designed for a single application to store its data in.

There are many other types of embedded database, of course.

And if you need multiple people to use the database from separate applications, then you have to install the database separately, and you can't bundle the database with the application.

Comment: will I already created the application with LINQ, so what to do now if I want to design a single application?
I'll be thankful if there is a step by step tutorial or something like that :\

Comment: I think we might need more details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to create a single application that will run with a local database 
I did all that with  LINQ and sql database , but now I am willing to make an installation file that install the wpf application with the database on the user side!